# VB.Net-How to get Oledb Command from Text Box

Tags: vb.net, ado.net, oledbcommand

I am running this code,its ok...

```
Sub CreateTable()

    Dim strCreate As String = "CREATE TABLE Info(" & _
        "CountryName varchar(120) Primary key," & _
        "Continent Integer," & _
        "Area Long," & _
        "Population Long," & _
        "Capital varchar(80)," & _
        "Code char(2));"

    Dim conDatabase As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
        "Data Source= " & filepath & ";")
    Dim cmdDatabase As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(strCreate, conDatabase)
    conDatabase.Open()
    cmdDatabase.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conDatabase.Close()
```

But When I am doing same through TextBox,its not working

```
Sub CreateTable()

    Dim strCreate As String = TextBox1.Text   'TextBox Contains Create table command

    Dim conDatabase As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
        "Data Source= " & filepath & ";")
    Dim cmdDatabase As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(strCreate, conDatabase)
    conDatabase.Open()
```

cmdDatabase.ExecuteNonQuery

conDatabase.Close()

Whats wrong here??

Comment: Are you getting an error message? If you compare the 'strCreate' from the textbox with the hard coded version do they match exactly? Also, are you missing some code from your examples? You just seem to open and close the database connection but never execute the command.

Comment: The code will work fine if you execute the command

Comment: Oh sorry....i skipped it...now i hv updated my ques.

Comment: Are you getting an error message? If you compare the 'strCreate' from the textbox with the hard coded version do they match exactly?

Comment: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException was unhandled
  ErrorCode=-2147217900
  HResult=-2147217900
  Message=Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'.
  Source=Microsoft JET Database Engine
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(Command

Comment: What happens if you compare the query text in the two versions? Do they match exactly? It looks like the query is just wrong in the second example.